# Horizentally flip of an image [python]

Tags: python

so I need to flip an image horizontally, meaning in regards to the horizontal axes, like this picture [image]

however my problem is it's flipping in regards to the vertical axes, as shown in this picture [image]

This is my code right now. May someone explain the changes I need to do ? image.gif is the image I am trying to flip. the reason I am setting the newImage at a new position as shown below is because I want the image to come up in the same window as the old image. and it did! only flipped vertically not horizontally.

```
from cImage import*
def horizentalFlip(oldimage):
    myimagewindow = ImageWin("image",1000,600)
    oldimage = FileImage("image.gif")
    oldimage.draw(myimagewindow)
    oldw = oldimage.getWidth()
    oldh = oldimage.getHeight()

    newImage = EmptyImage(oldw,oldh)

    maxp = oldw - 1
    for row in range(oldh):
        for col in range(oldw):
            oldpixel = oldimage.getPixel(maxp-col,row)
            newImage.setPixel(col,row,oldpixel)
    newImage.setPosition(oldw+1,0)
    newImage.draw(myimagewindow)
    myimagewindow.exitOnClick()
```

Thank you

Comment: Why not use pillow for image processing?

Comment: because we r required to use cImage.

Comment: Oh ok. I get it now. Did I have the wrong concept all of my life? or did the word change it's meaning? The picture you posted makes so much sense.
I was confused with photoshop right now.So based on the answer, flip horizontally means Move/Spin the horizontal access, which in return, will make it spin around the vertical access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of flipping you want (reflection around the x axis, your first picture) is *usually* called a "vertical" flip,  whereas reflection around the y axis (your second picture) is usually called a horizontal flip.

Nomenclature aside, you want reflection about the x axis and if I've understood you correctly your problem is that you're getting reflection about the y axis.  This is because the following lines:

```
  maxp = oldw - 1
  ...
        oldpixel = oldimage.getPixel(maxp-col,row)
```

manipulate widths (`w`), columns (`col`) and the *first* coordinate argument of each `getPixel` call:  all these concepts are relevant to manipulation of the *horizontal* coordinate of each pixel. But you want to change the *vertical* coordinate of each pixel, so you need to work with height, with rows, and with the second coordinate argument:

```
  maxp = oldh - 1
  ...
        oldpixel = oldimage.getPixel(col, maxp - row)
```

Comment: That was the problem ! It seemed I was a little bit confused about rows and columns in regards to x and y axis. Thank you for the help